# Autenticação yii através do modulo user

Tags: yii

Estou a usar o modulo user yii cujo [código está neste link](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-user/), só que na minha base de dados eu também  tenho uma tabela cliente.

É possível usar o login do modulo user para autenticar o cliente ou tenho que criar outro login para cliente? Ou posso relacionar a tabela cliente com a tabela user do módulo?

Answer (score 1):

Tem como fazer sim, porém você terá de criar o model e adaptar as funções de login para pegar do model novo com suas regras.

Ainda acho que seria mais prático fazer um login do zero.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar os dois, e colocar uma FK no seu cliente direcionando ao login da extensão.

Não é muito bonito criar uma relação 1 para 1, mas resolve seus problemas. Quando o usuário logar, existirá apenas um cliente que tem aquele id de usuário, então você sabe qual é o cliente que esta logado.

Answer (score 0):

A melhor solução seria refatorar para utilizar apenas um login, poderias utilizar o RBAC para definir as regras de acesso para cada Perfil/Login também. Fazendo desta maneira, terás menos trabalho caso o projeto que estás trabalhando seja escalável.